# Spring Cloud Config + Eureka + Zuul - not seeing properties in clients

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I am developing an application with microservice-based arhitecture using Spring Cloud.

I have four applications currently in project:

`config-server`, `eureka-server`, `gateway-service(zuul)` and `eureka-client` which I am using just to test that the project works as intended.

But I have a problem fetching properties from the config-server.
I have a git repository in which I have one file, `eureka-client.yml`.
This file has one property `message: test message`.

I can see that the property is loaded into the config-server if I go to http://localhost:8888/eureka-client/default.

But when I access the property in my eureka-client it returns null.

> environment.getProperty("message");

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm probably just missing a configuration or .yml property but can't find out which one.

Also the clients are supposed to fetch the properties from the config-server through Eureka.

EDIT:

eureka-server - application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

eureka-client - application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8082
```

And annotated with @EnableDiscoveryClient

config-server - application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/bpuscasu/config-server
```

And annotated with @EnableConfigServer and @EnableDiscoveryClient

Comment: It could be anything. Can you please update your question with the configuration of the eureka-client and config server and any relevant logs?

Comment: I updated my original question. Thank you.

Comment: I need the client app too

Comment: Client application has following dependencies: spring-cloud-starter-config, spring-cloud-starter-eureka. annotated with EnableDiscoveryClient and has a RestController in which I autowired an Environment. Nothing more.

Comment: so far, none of this has anything to do with eureka. Does the eureka-client have a spring-cloud-starter-config dependency?